# How to sum up yes and no into a total quantity, using matplotlib, pandas, python from a CSV import to plot a graph

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

[m [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6cDD.png)

QUESTION #1)    I am new to python and coding in general. I want to take my data from a CSV which has a column labeled "U.S. OSHA Recordable?". In that column every answer is either "yes" or "no". I want to display a plot.bar that shows "23 yes's" and  "7 No's". Essentially adding up the total of "yes's" and "no's in the column, then displaying the total in 1 clean bar graphs. It will display 2 bars with the total number on top of both bars.... The problem is, the bar graph has a single line on the X axis right now and each line says "no, yes, no, yes, yes, no" about 27 individual times. I want the users to easily see 1 bar graph showing only 2 bars with the total on top like this image.

This is my code, I am not sure what i would need to sum up the Yes and No in the column.

```
import pandas as pd # powerful data visualization library
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # allows us to plot things
import csv # allows us to import and use CSV commands which are simple but effective


data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rmond\Downloads\PS_csvFile.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1", skiprows=6) #skiprows allows you to skip the comments on top... & ecoding allows pandas to work on this CSV
data.head() # this will give the first row that you want it to read the header
data.plot.bar(x='U.S. OSHA Recordable?') #creates a plot in pandas
plt.show() # shows the plot to the user
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['Val'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Here `Val` is the name of the column that contains 'Yes' & 'No'

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. You really helped me research things in a new direction. I just came up with a totally different solution, but answered my own question. I will post it right now below

Comment: If my answer helped you can consider up-voting/accepting. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it will not let me yet. I says I need 15 reputation points before I can vote. I am new to this, or else I would upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd # powerful data visualization library
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # allows us to plot things
import csv # allows us to import and use CSV commands which are simple but effective
import seaborn as sns # it counts everything for you and outputs it exactly like I want
# This website saved my life https://www.pythonforengineers.com/introduction-to-pandas/
# use this to check the available styles: plt.style.available


data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\rmond\Downloads\PS_csvFile.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1", skiprows=6) #skiprows allows you to skip the comments on top... & ecoding allows pandas to work on this CSV
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
ax = sns.countplot(x='U.S. OSHA Recordable?', data=data)
plt.show() # shows the plot to the user
```

So interestingly enough I found out about "seaborn" I pip installed it and gave it a shot. It is supposed to pull data from a URL, but after viewing a few other pages on stack overflow I found a great suggestion. Anyways, this works great and it does everything for me. I am so happy with this solution. Now onto the next problem lol. I hope this helps someone else in the future.

My graph looks exactly like the one posted by SH-SF btw. Works great